# Android Studio error: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, runtime-error

I am trying to use iBeacon code in my app, when there are no beacons around, the app just keeps searching for them, but when my app finds a beacon it crashes.I am new at android development and did not have much experience at debugging. Appreciate all the help. Thanks in advance.  Here is the Error code:

```
11-20 11:23:34.529  15407-15407/com.example.marik.pinafly W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x418acda0)
11-20 11:23:34.529  15407-15419/com.example.marik.pinafly D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ onScanResult() - Device=61:78:1A:F3:10:97 RSSI=-93
11-20 11:23:34.549  15407-15407/com.example.marik.pinafly E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.marik.pinafly, PID: 15407
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class com.estimote.examples.demos.DistanceBackgroundView
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at com.example.marik.pinafly.LeDeviceListAdapter.inflateIfRequired(LeDeviceListAdapter.java:72)
            at com.example.marik.pinafly.LeDeviceListAdapter.getView(LeDeviceListAdapter.java:56)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2738)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1811)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:697)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:763)
            at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1627)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2563)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15762)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4880)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15762)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4880)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15762)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4880)
            at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:459)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15762)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4880)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15762)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4880)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2356)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2069)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6637)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:814)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:614)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:584)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:800)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.estimote.examples.demos.DistanceBackgroundView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.example.marik.pinafly-6.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.marik.pinafly-6, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:67)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:565)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
            at com.example.marik.pinafly.LeDeviceListAdapter.inflateIfRequired(LeDeviceListAdapter.java:72)
            at com.example.marik.pinafly.LeDeviceListAdapter.getView(LeDeviceListAdapter.java:56)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2738)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1811)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:697)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:763)
            at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1627)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2563)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15762)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4880)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15762)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4880)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15762)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4880)
            at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:459)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15762)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4880)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15762)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4880)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2356)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2069)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1254)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6637)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:814)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:614)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:584)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:800)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

DistanceBackgroundView.java file

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

/**
 * Draws distance background that is stretched to parent's height, keeps aspect ration
 * and centers the image.
 *
 * @author wiktor@estimote.com (Wiktor Gworek)
 */
public class DistanceBackgroundView extends View {

    private final Drawable drawable;

    public DistanceBackgroundView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        drawable = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bg_distance);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        int width = drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() * canvas.getHeight() / drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
        int deltaX = (width - canvas.getWidth()) / 2;
        drawable.setBounds(-deltaX, 0, width - deltaX, canvas.getHeight());
        drawable.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Manifest File

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.marik.pinafly">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="HIDDEN" />
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".BluetoothActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.TAB" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MapActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_map">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.pinafly.LoginActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity2"
            android:label="App Activities" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ImagePickActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_image_pick_avtivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".AllDemosActivity"
            android:label="Demos"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".ListBeaconsActivity"
            android:label="Select Beacon" />

        <activity
        android:name=".DistanceBeaconActivity"
        android:label="Distance Demo" />



        <activity
            android:name=".NotifyDemoActivity"
            android:label="Notify Demo" />

        <activity
            android:name=".CharacteristicsDemoActivity"
            android:label="Characteristics Demo" />

        <!-- Estimote service responsible for scanning beacons. -->
        <service
            android:name="com.estimote.sdk.service.BeaconService"
            android:exported="false" />
    </application>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="18"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="permission_name" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapdemoapiv2.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />


    <!-- Declaration that this app is usable on phones with Bluetooth Low Energy. -->
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
        android:required="true" />


    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />

    <service
        android:name="com.estimote.sdk.service.BeaconService"
        android:exported="false" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.estimote.examples.demos.DistanceBackgroundView"` and please don't post your API key in the manifest. You can safely delete that.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, forgot that API keys are in the manifest. Do you have a suggestion on a solution? I am new to debugging, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: have you added any external libraries? Or copy-pasted the code from somewhere? :)

Comment: yes I got the above code from the estimote android sdk repository. It is for iBeacons. I did add their library into my libs folder and all imports from the estimore Android SDK are recognized. The repository URL is https://github.com/Estimote/Android-SDK/tree/master/Demos/src/main/java/com/estimote/examples/demos

Answer (score 0):

Because `com.estimote.examples.demos.DistanceBackgroundView`
is the demo project path . You need just to change the path :

```
yourProjectPath.DistanceBackgroundView
```